# Error 1004 when clearing a row in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently building a macro for excel and when I try and run it it randomly breaks
on lines when I try to clear a column.
It ALWAYS throws error 1004 and I don't know how to fix it since I'm quite new to Excel VBA.

This is the code it breaks on (with varying columns):

```
Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Clear
```

Is this the wrong way of doing it? Should I use another function to clear columns?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you don't specify to which worksheet a range refers to, it is refered to the active worksheet. Try

```
Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A3", Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Clear
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it! Stupid of me that I didn't see that. I'll accept your answer as the right answer when I can. (timer thing)

Comment: By the way, I hope you are not really using `Sheet` as a variable name. Are you?

Comment: Yes I am. Why? I only use one variable per function so it isn't much of a problem as for naming conventions.

Comment: It's just that it is already a name of a type in VBA and you really should avoid this ambiguity whenever possible, because it may lead to: 1. confusion, 2. unpredictable behaviour, 3. errors

Comment: Ok. I didn't know. I'll change it. Thank you very much!